# Dynamics 365 portal odata list URL exception

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, adxstudio-portals

After Portal data deployed on the Production server facing below error but same is working on the sandbox server fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises when the portal could not found CRM view id in Dynamics 365 Production instance which is required for OData to fetch data.

Go to Entity List record and check and select view if already exist or else you have to move or create the customization solution for the view. Hope this helps.